# Verizon HTC M8 One - Vanilla lollipop

Tags: 5.0-lollipop, verizon, htc-one-m8

What i want is to be able to turn my verizon htc m8 one into a vanilla install of android 5.0. Is this possible? I am having trouble finding info online. I can find info on being able to root and "unlock" the bootloaded but it all seems to use some software side tricks that i think will give me a vanilla rom on KitKat but upgrading to 5.0 isn't supported. If i am a wrong AWESOME. Any help would be useful.